# Shared folder not accessible

Tags: shared-folders

Ubuntu 14.04. Two harddrives. I have created a folder on the slave drive and made it a shared folder using Nautilus. I can see the folder from another computer, but I can't see what's in it. Access denied. Why? I have folders on my primary drive shared, and that works just fine!

Comment: Are you able to access it using terminal?

Comment: That is called "permissions". Please provide an `ls -l` for the drive mountpoint and the 1st directory inside the drive. rwx permissions, owner and group need to be set to your case.

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu. Whats a mountpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If setting the shares up through Nautilus make sure the "allow others to create and delete files in this folder" box is ticked.

Comment: It's ticked. And the geust-account box as well.

Comment: I've never used the guest account box, so I don't know if that has any bearing or not.